# Get object from signal function being called

Tags: c++, qt

Is possible to get the `object` of the control (button, checkbox, etc) which belongs

to the function being called other than declaring her 'type' ?

Example:

```
void Main::on_toolButton_pressed()
{    
    QToolButton *btn = qobject_cast<QToolButton*>(sender());    
}
```

To something like:

```
void Main::on_toolButton_pressed()
{    
    auto *btn = qobject_cast<??>( sender() );
}
```

where `??` is something containing the button type.

Comment: As already told you in another forum this is not possible. Do a qobject_cast<> to your distinct classes, check if it succeeded and work with it. Or use the common base class (e.g. QbstractButton)

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a mix of compile time knowledge with runtime knowledge. That is not possible. What you can do is perform some "reflection stuff" using qt meta functionality like calling `invokeMethod` doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod. Check QMetaObject class and what you can do. Basically if you have `QObject` there is a possibility to query class name, members, fields etc. If you are willing to write a code that will then cast your pointer to specific class based on moc introspection, then you will have perfectly working c++ code.